# Logic App Recurrence at Different Hours & Minutes

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have a Logic App that we need to run Monday - Friday at 10:00AM, 2:15PM, 4:30PM & 7:45PM. We have selected Frequency "Week" the days "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday", but we are not seeing a way to setup a schedule like this without creating 4 separate recurrence Logic Apps that all do the same thing, but trigger at different times. Is this possible?

As you can see from the "Preview", this would run too frequently & at undesirable times:

[image: Logic App Recurrence Interface]

Comment: No, in Logic apps its not Possible to do your requirement for now, i would suggest you to use more workflows for different times

Comment: 4 apps won’t hurt you. Just make sure you have one app that those 4 flow into which has all of the business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @Skin, you can have 4 triggers having 4 flows respectively to achieve your requirement. However, you can have multiple triggers for a single flow using **code view** of your logic apps. For demonstration purposes, I tried to run the flow at 10:44, 10:45, 10:46. However, you can change the time as per your requirement. Below is the code view of my logic app.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "Sample Execution",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Week",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "hours": [
                            "10"
                        ],
                        "minutes": [
                            44
                        ],
                        "weekDays": [
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday"
                        ]
                    },
                    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                },
                "type": "recurrence"
            },
            "Recurrence_2": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Week",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "hours": [
                            "10"
                        ],
                        "minutes": [
                            45
                        ],
                        "weekDays": [
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday"
                        ]
                    },
                    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                },
                "type": "recurrence"
            },
            "Recurrence_3": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Week",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "hours": [
                            "10"
                        ],
                        "minutes": [
                            46
                        ],
                        "weekDays": [
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday"
                        ]
                    },
                    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                },
                "type": "recurrence"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:** One downside is that, If you are going to follow this method, Make sure you save the flow somewhere before adding multiple triggers because once you add multiple triggers and go back to designer from code view, the whole flow gets erased. So you need to build the whole flow first in the designer and then add multiple triggers at last in code view.